# What does the $s$ represent in an equation obtained by taking a Laplace transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

If we have a simple RLC circuit like this one, we can say that $$V(t)=I(t)R+\frac{\int^t_0 I\space dt}{C}+L\frac{dI}{dt}(t).$$
If we apply the Laplace transform to both sides, we get
$$V(s)=I(s)R+\frac{I(s)}{Cs}+LsI(s).$$
I understand that the first equation is a dynamic equation (all variables are a functions in time) but I really don't understand what the $s$ here represents.

[image]

Comment: Check your definition of the Laplace transform.